# Why is this "expression" not modifiable?

Tags: c++

I have a class called **CircuitProfiler** that has a public member function *switchState*. Below is the code for it:

```
void CircuitProfiler::switchState(int index)
{
    if (profilingNode)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0:
            node->getVoltage().isKnown = !node->getVoltage().isKnown;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code I am having trouble with is the line:

`node->getVoltage().isKnown = !node->getVoltage().isKnown;`

I am getting error that says "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". There is a red line under **node**.

**node** is a pointer to an instance of a **Node** class that I created. **node** a private data member of **CircuitProfiler**. It is declared in **CircuitProfiler** as `Node* node;`

**Node** has a private data member called **voltage**, and *getVoltage* is a public member function of **Node** that simply returns **voltage**. **voltage** is declared in **Node** as `VariableValue<float> voltage;` and the code for *getVoltage* is:

```
VariableValue<float> Node::getVoltage()
{
    return voltage;
}
```

**voltage** is an instance of a simple struct called **VariableValue**, the code for which is below.

```
template <class T>
struct VariableValue {
    T value;
    bool isKnown;
};
```

So why am I getting the error "expression must be a modifiable value"? Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: you'd likely want `VariableValue<float>& Node::getVoltage()`, i.e., return by reference. Otherwise you'd be modifying a temporary in the `=` call.

Comment: Read the error more carefully, you should find it say "modifiable lvalue", not "modifiable value"

Comment: `GetVoltage()` returns by value so it returns an rvalue (loosely, a value that is on the right of an assignment expression).  Among other things that means the returned value will cease to exist at the end of the current statement, and modifications to it are meaningless.    C++, by design, treats such deeds as a diagnosable error.   If you want to modify the underlying `voltage` object that it returns, change the function so it returns a reference, not by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially saying (MCVE):

```
struct S { int i; }; // S as VariableValue<float>
 
S f() { return S{}; } // f as getVoltage
 
f().i =  1; // i as isKnown
```

You return a temporary in getVoltage(), which does not bind to an lvalue argument of `operator=()`.

Likely you wanted to return `voltage` by reference in `getVoltage()`, if you wanted to use it this way, i.e.,

```
VariableValue<float>& Node::getVoltage()
{
    return voltage;
}
```

You might also define a const version of it.

Comment: Minor nitpick: since the operands are both built-in type, `=` here is the built-in assignment operator, it is not a function nor an overloaded operator.  The built-in assignment operator requires a modifiable lvalue as left operand; `operator=()` does not have such a restriction

Comment: Thank you. Your exact solution alone was not enough, but I solved my issue by also modifying the switchState function such that it uses an intermediate VariableValue<float> instance.